# Can I connect a Raspberry Pi and a servo shield to a single power supply?

Tags: power-supply, power, raspberry-pi, battery-operated, servo

I'm building a robot that requires 12 servos and a Raspberry Pi. I will be using the Adafruit 16-channel servo shield(https://www.adafruit.com/product/1411) and a Raspberry Pi 3B. Of course, if they were both connected to the same power supply, it would be way easier to turn the system on and off.

Is there any way to do it, even with additional pieces or arrangements? If so, how?

Also, could the power supply be a battery? What characteristics should it have?

Comment: This is not answerable without details of the components.  Generally though, sharing power supplies would be a bad idea.   Probably what you should do is use something like a 12v gel cell and get multiple switching power converters (perhaps RC hobby or drone "battery eliminators") to divide the load, ie, have one just for the pi, and another for every 3 or 4 servos.  These modules would need to be of a type that can have a common ground on the input and output. Done right, an overload from a jammed servo would be limited by a current limit in that power converter, and not brown out the pi.

Comment: I will be using 12 MG90 micro servos (which draw a couple hundred mA when moving) and either a Raspberry Pi or an Arduino UNO board, depending on the final code. All the components in the circuit work on 5V. My only issue is powering the servo board and the main board with the same power supply, and it would be great if the solution weren't very sturdy. Could I make it work with power converters and a battery?

Comment: If you use separate power converters it can probably work; if you use the same one for the pi and servos you may see no end of trouble.

Comment: So do you think I could connect two power converters to a single battery and then connect one to the raspberry/arduino board and the other to the servo shield and it would work?

Comment: If the battery has sufficient power capacity compared to the load and  is of sufficiently higher voltage that even with load droop it still meets the regulator minimum input...

Comment: Right now I'm considering a 2S3P battery pack or similar, as Tony Steward has proposed. I'll be using 12 MG90S servos which will draw approximately 3.6 Ah, according to their characteristics online. The 2S3P pack gives out 7.4V and 7.5Ah. Also, I think I'll be using an Arduino board in the end (much cheaper). As you might have noticed, I'm not an expert in electrical circuits. Would it be possible to connect the battery pack to two power converters, each hooked to their own board with their own configuration, and make it work?

Comment: 2S won't be enough.  Really I think you should use gel cells, but if you have to go lithium, go for 3S with a suitable switching step down converter, one for the computer, one for each group of several servos.

Comment: Oh, i could use a gel cell if you think that's best. I suppose a 6v 4Ah cell would suffice, but again, i'm sure you know more about it. If i were to pick said gel cell, would i still need the step down converters? Also, the servo shields usually have a single input and output for external power: would a step down converter for the whole shield not be enough?

Comment: No, again, you need a substantially higher voltage.  Aim for a 12v gel cell to feed the step down converters.

Comment: May I ask why I would need that much voltage? Wouldn't a 7,4V battery work? They'd be connected in parallel, so the main issue would be the current, right?

Comment: Again, you need a higher voltage because of load droop, and because the power converter needs an input voltage a bit above the output.  Under load later in its discharge your 2s pack might only give you 6 volts, which is insufficient.  You want 3s, or much more simply a 12v nominal gel cell, or 10 NiCd's.

Comment: 12v gel cells are way too sturdy and heavy for my project (but still a candidate nonetheless) so I'm leaning more towards a 3s3p battery pack. If I were to pick it, would the power converters be enough to make the circuit work?

Comment: If you get RC hobby power converters designed to run servos in a 3s plane, yes, each will be able to run *some number of* servos.  Then get another battery eliminator to give you clean 5 volts for the computer.  It's better not to use something like an Arduino's linear regulator with a 12v source, although not out of spec such a large voltage drop puts a lot of stress on it.

Comment: I've looked for it, but I've found nothing: what do you mean by 3s plane? Is it a special requisite for 3S3P batteries?

If I got about four step-down buck converters (one for the arduino board, one for every four servos) and connected them directly to the battery pack and the boards, would the system work?

By the way, I don't intend to use any servos with a moving range greater than 180 degrees, meaning that I won't need any of the continuously rotating, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Read the fine#§* manual RTFM

```
5v 10A switching power supply (http://adafru.it/658) (up to perhaps 16 servos).  V
4xAA Battery Holder (http://adafru.it/830) - 6v with Alkaline cells.     
4.8v with NiMH rechargeable cells, portable!    
4.8 or 6v Rechargeable RC battery packs from a hobby store.
```

https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-16-channel-pwm-slash-servo-shield.pdf?timestamp=1598199855

Each servo under max load draws 1A . Estimate your Ah or Wh needs and dont undersize it.

It you overvoltage with 2S3P Li Ion you must control acceleration not just position to avoid over heating servos but that might work. A battery balancer extends life.

Comment: Thank you!!! It's a relatively small project, and all the battery balancers i'm finding are very big. I'm looking for power converters. Do you think I could connect two power converters to a 2S3P pack or similar and then connect each power converter to a board?

Comment: It depends on the implementation.  some chips no, some floating chargers yes.

Comment: What do you mean by floating chargers?

Comment: Not earth grounded output. https://lmgtfy.com/?q=What+do+you+mean+by+Floating+chargers&iie=1

Comment: While 4xNiCd is indeed what hobby servos were designed to run on back in the day, that's not going to run a Raspberry Pi or an Arduino.   A 3v3 Arduino or (if alkalines are never used) an unregulated ATmega can work however.  But something like a pi is going to need a switching converter, typically stepping down from a higher voltage.